# vb6 how to check a conflict time using sql

Tags: vb6

My problem is how can i check if theres a conflict time. And if theres a time conflict it will not add the record and it display the conflict record in the other listview.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to be more specific and supply your code. It's not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: `If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
rs.Open "select * from tblSchedule WHERE !time1 BETWEEN #" & cmbtime1.Text & "# AND #" & cmbtime2.Text& "# ", dbconn, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
                If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "conflict"
        Do While Not conflict.EOF
        Call sched_conflict
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "No Conflict"
End If`

Comment: @red: [Edit] your question with the details rather then adding a comment. And I'll also point out, your code doesn't really make your question any clearer.